# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning while overwriting column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert `string` to `datetime` and assigning it to original column

```
df = dfMain[dfMain["Exception"] == "PriorCancel"]
df["CRE_DTTM"] = pd.to_datetime(df["CRE_DTTM"], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

but I am getting `SettingWithCopyWarning`. I then tried

```
df.loc[:, "CRE_DTTM"] = pd.to_datetime(df["CRE_DTTM"], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

But I still get the same warning.

Comment: What is code before `df["CRE_DTTM"] = pd.to_datetime(dfC["CRE_DTTM"], format='%Y-%m-%d')` ? How is created `df` ?

Comment: I have updated the code. The link you posted does not help.

Comment: Use `df = dfMain[dfMain["Exception"] == "PriorCancel"].copy()`

Comment: Thanks, using `.copy()` does not give the error. Even when I use `df["CRE_DTTM"] = pd.to_datetime(df["CRE_DTTM"], format='%Y-%m-%d')` or `df.loc[:, "CRE_DTTM"] = pd.to_datetime(df["CRE_DTTM"], format='%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: If you modify values in `df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`dfMain`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for you help @jezrael